# Understanding the syntax : crc ^= *((unsigned char *)memptr)++;

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-errors

I want to understand this syntax to fix it for crc16 function :

```
unsigned short crc16(void *memptr, int len) {
  int j;
  unsigned short crc = CRC16_INIT ;
  while(len--){
    crc ^= *((unsigned char *)memptr)++;
    for(j=0; j<8; j++){
      if(crc & 1)
        crc =(USHORT)( (crc>>1) ^ CRC16_POLY );
      else
        crc =(USHORT)( crc>>1);
    }//for
  }//while
  return crc ;
}
```

it was working code on older compiler and now I 've got

> error : IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

on this line:

```
crc ^= *((unsigned char *)memptr)++;
```

> Compiler error : error C2105: '++' needs l-value

Recoded to it (hope it's correct):

```
unsigned char oldValue = *((unsigned char *)memptr);
++*((unsigned char *)memptr);
crc ^= oldValue; // <--- WRONG



crc ^= (*((unsigned char *)memptr))++;  // <--- WRONG
```

Comment: Your recoded code is not correct, in my opinion. See my answer.

Comment: Because your code doesn't increment the pointer. Its always the same, pointing to same memory location!

Comment: I think I found a better solution : crc ^= (*((unsigned char *)memptr))++;

Comment: I wonder how `(*((unsigned char *)memptr))++; ` will work, as it doesn't increment `memptr`. It uses same byte again and again!

Comment: I seriously doubt that what you have done will give you a correct crc for a passed in buffer - but if you think it does and your testing shows it's what you need - then fair dues...

Comment: @Nawaz I am wondering because crc ^= *((unsigned char *)memptr)++;
 and crc ^= (*((unsigned char *)memptr))++; is not the same. Tested on old compiler and your solution work pretty good. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASM-version of this function (not that optimized, but still 0x59 bytes vs my compiler's 0x69 of C++ version).

If you are familiar with ASM, it will be enough to understand mentioned C++ code segment and the whole function overall.

```
unsigned short crc16(void *memptr, int len)
{
 unsigned short crc = 0;//CRC16_INIT;

 __asm
 {
  MOV       ESI, len
while_s:
  DEC       ESI
  CMP       ESI, 0
  JL        while_e
  XOR       EAX, EAX
  MOV       AX, WORD PTR DS:[crc]
  MOV       EBX, len
  SUB       EBX, ESI
  DEC       EBX
  MOV       ECX, memptr
  MOV       BL, BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+EBX]
  XOR       AL, BL
  XOR       BL, BL
 for_s:
  CMP       BL, 8
  JGE       for_e
  INC       BL
  MOV       DX, AX
  SHR       AX, 1
  AND       DX, 1
  JE        for_j
  XOR       AX, 0xA001//CRC16_POLY
 for_j:
  JMP       for_s
 for_e:
  MOV       WORD PTR DS:[crc], AX
  JMP       while_s
while_e:
  XOR       EAX, EAX
  MOV       AX, WORD PTR DS:[crc]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
crc ^= *((unsigned char *)memptr)++;
```

Change the above line to this:

```
unsigned char *pchar=(unsigned char *)memptr; //casting to unsigned char*
crc = crc ^ pchar[0];                          //XOR computation
memptr = ++pchar;                           //incrementing the pointer by 1 byte
```

Your code doesn't work because `((unsigned char *)memptr)` gives a rvalue which cannot be incremented. Your old compiler had bug.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Actually there was some mistake. I corrected it now. :-_

Comment: @Nawaz, still wrong, the code doesn't change `*memptr`, it changes `memptr`. Usual `*p++` idiom.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Yeah. I got confused with the precedence thing. Now I think, its correct.

Comment: But the result you described in your answer was intended, obviously. +1

Answer (score 1):

Break that line up:

1. `(unsigned char *)memptr` - this casts the `void*` (argument) to an `unsigned char*`
2. `++` - post increment, i.e. increment and return the previous value (i.e. the *pointer is incremented* - note: this is a local copy)
3. `*()` - this dereferences the contents of the previous value of pointer (so now we have an `unsigned char`)
4. `^=` xor with current value of `crc`

As ZeRemz mentions in his comment, the order of the operators applied here is what is generating this error.

To fix, this you need to understand what the original intention is (and fixes)

1. Update the pointer and xor the previous value

   `unsigned char* t = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(memptr);
   ..
   crc ^= *(t++);`
2. Update the value of the character and use it's previous value (though this does not make much sense for generating a CRC)

   `crc ^= (*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(memptr))++;`

Comment: looks like his compiler doesn't think that `(unsigned char*)memptr` is an lvalue. Or is it the compiler? What it that IntelliSense thing about?

Comment: Actually, ++ takes precedence over * so the post-increment is applied first. The error message is due to the fact that the result of the cast is a temporary pointer, which is not an l-value so it can't be incremented (whereas the result of dereferencing _is_ a lvalue so it would have been legal code if the * had been applied first)

Comment: Good, I hope that I understood it correct :) check my new version

Comment: `++*typedMemptr;` is incorrect, here you are updating the value (after dereferencing the pointer), I think what you want is `++typedMemptr;` - which increments the pointer (i.e. moves to the next character in the buffer (which is what a CRC algorithm typically uses.

Comment: why so ? I increase the *Value of typedMemptr.

Comment: Because `*typedMemptr` is dereferencing the `unsigned char` that is pointed to by `typedMemptr`, and you are incrementing that value - which for a CRC algorithm does not make sense. You want to xor the values of *all the characters in the buffer* (which you will get by incrementing the pointer...)